# Im making calculator and when i add numbers 1+1 in my input i get answer 1. why

Tags: javascript, html, math, input

input value = "1+1" but when  i console.log(salyga) i am getting answer "1"  . Also if I only put + in input and I console log it I am getting answer NaN, I don't understand why math is not working.
Also if I change input type="number" I'm getting this error (The specified value "+" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.)

```js
let salyga = document.querySelector(".container__langai--salyga");

const vienas = document.querySelector("#vienas");
const one = +vienas.value
vienas.addEventListener("click", number1);

function number1() {
  salyga.value += one
}

const lygu = document.querySelector("#lygu");
const equal = lygu.value
lygu.addEventListener("click", opLygu);

const plius = document.querySelector("#plius");
const plus = plius.value
plius.addEventListener("click", opPlius);

function opLygu() {
  console.log(parseFloat(salyga.value))
}

function opPlius() {
  salyga.value += plus
}
```

```html
<input value="" type="text" placeholder="0" class="container__langai--salyga"></input>
<button id="vienas" class="number" value="1">1</button>
<button id="lygu" value="=" class="operator">=</button>
<button id="plius" value="+" class="operator">+</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve that problem, here's information. Text that are get from  tags are always String, it doesn't matter even if you set the input's type to number, so convert it to either int or float by using the parseInt() and the parseFloat() respectively. A sample down below is shown to demonstrate the correct usage.

```
alert(parseInt(document.getElementById("input_name").value));

alert(parseFloat(document.getElementById("input_name").value));
```

Comment: but i did                 const one = +vienas.value, its same as                                                const one = parseInt(vienas.value)

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp):

> This function determines if the first character in the specified string is a number. If >it is, it parses the string until it reaches the end of the number, and returns the number > as a number, not as a string.
> Note: Only the first number in the string is returned!

So when you pass `1+1` to the `parseFloat`, it will return only `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code `document.querySelector("#vienas");` produces a **collection** of DOM elements, not a single element as you seem to be expecting. It does not matter if only 1 element is found, it still returns a collection (with 1 item in it).

To get the item directly, use [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById):

```
const vienas = document.getElementById("vienas");
```